# How can I access the overall test result of a pytest test run during runtime?

Tags: python, pytest

Dependent on the overall test result of a `pytest` test run I would like to execute conditional tear down. This means the access to the overall test result must happen after all tests have been executed but before the test runner has been left. How can I achieve this?

Comment: In the pytest docs the [post-process test reports / failures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#post-process-test-reports-failures) describes how to access the result of a single test (pytest hook `pytest_runtest_makereport`). I could not find a suitable [pytest hook](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/src/_pytest/hookspec.py) to access the overall test result yet.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I could not find a suitable pytest hook to access the overall test result yet.

You don't need one; just collect the test results yourself. This is the blueprint I usually use when in need of accessing the test results in batch:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest


def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    session.results = dict()


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    result = outcome.get_result()

    if result.when == 'call':
        item.session.results[item] = result
```

Now all test results are stored under `session.results` dict; example usage:

```
# conftest.py (continued)

def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    print()
    print('run status code:', exitstatus)
    passed_amount = sum(1 for result in session.results.values() if result.passed)
    failed_amount = sum(1 for result in session.results.values() if result.failed)
    print(f'there are {passed_amount} passed and {failed_amount} failed tests')
```

Running the tests will yield:

```
$ pytest -sv
================================== test session starts ====================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.7.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.7.1 -- /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-51711988, inifile:
collected 3 items

test_spam.py::test_spam PASSED
test_spam.py::test_eggs PASSED
test_spam.py::test_fail FAILED
run status code: 1
there are 2 passed and 1 failed tests


======================================== FAILURES =========================================
_______________________________________ test_fail _________________________________________

    def test_fail():
>       assert False
E       assert False

test_spam.py:10: AssertionError
=========================== 1 failed, 2 passed in 0.05 seconds ============================
```

In case the overall `pytest` exit code (`exitstatus`) is sufficient info (info about # passed, # failed, etc. not required) use the following:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    print()
    print('run status code:', exitstatus)
```

#### Accessing the error

You can access the error details from the `call.excinfo` object:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    result = outcome.get_result()
    if result.outcome == "failed":
        exception = call.excinfo.value
        exception_class = call.excinfo.type
        exception_class_name = call.excinfo.typename
        exception_type_and_message_formatted = call.excinfo.exconly()
        exception_traceback = call.excinfo.traceback
```

Comment: Great. I did not come up with this `pytest_sessionstart`, `pytest_runtest_makereport`, `pytest_sessionfinish` approach. Thx a lot.

Comment: It's slightly off-topic: If I would like to communicate the overall test result with a CI job to e.g. store a CI artifact in case of failing overall test result this should be possible by setting an environment variable I guess.

Comment: Are you talking with Jenkins in mind or is this some other CI server?

Comment: In this case it's about gitlab-ci.

Comment: In case I would just be interested in the overall test result [`pytest_sessionfinish(..., exitstatus)`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=exitstatus#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionfinish) could be sufficient. But the conditions for different `exitstatus`codes is not documented here. I assume it'd be `1` as soon as one test failed...?

Comment: Oh, I see. Indeed, writing serialized data (XML/JSON/etc) to an environment variable or even a file in workspace seems to be the most straightfoward approach.

Comment: The exit codes are documented [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#possible-exit-codes).

Comment: How can I get the Exception message from the hook?. Just I see you can get PASSED/FAILED but I would like to get access to the Exception message and stack trace.

Comment: @FrankEscobar you can access the error via `call.excinfo` if an error was raised; you can detect the stage the exception was raised (setup, call, teardown) at via additionally checking `result.when`. I have added an example snippet to the answer.