# How to access the overall runtime in pytest?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

There is the overview in pytest after running the test:

============= 7 passed in 1.11 seconds ============

I like to access the time (here the 1.11) in the end of pytest.

some helpful information I found already here:

[How can I access the overall test result of a pytest test run during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711988/how-can-i-access-the-overall-test-result-of-a-pytest-test-run-during-runtime)

But did not match the overall test run time.

I tried to use the def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus)

I did not find the overall duration there.

It looks like the value is inside the RunResult object.
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/_modules/_pytest/pytester.html#RunResult

How to access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access execution start timestamp in the `TerminalReporter` plugin instance, then just calculate the execution time yourself (this is also what `pytest` itself does). Example:

```
# conftest.py

import time

def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    reporter = session.config.pluginmanager.get_plugin('terminalreporter')
    duration = time.time() - reporter._sessionstarttime
    reporter.write_sep('=', 'duration: {} seconds'.format(duration), yellow=True, bold=True)
```

#### Update

As noted by [looki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506110/looki) in the comments, this will not return the overall execution time when running the tests distributed with `pytest-xdist` as each process becomes its own session instance. Switch to the [`pytest_unconfigure`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_unconfigure) hook (the implementation is almost the same):

```
def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    reporter = config.pluginmanager.get_plugin('terminalreporter')
    duration = time.time() - reporter._sessionstarttime
    reporter.write_sep('=', 'duration: {} seconds'.format(duration), yellow=True, bold=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, 
first this helped and worked.
But if I use xdist plugin, the session is per xdist core.

So now I use 
def pytest_unconfigure(config):
hook instead to check after all session.

Comment: Fair point, I have updated the answer (btw using a more fancy printing via `TerminalReporter` now, with separator and colors). Thanks for the heads-up!