# Pytest run all tests twice and compare results bet mock and real

Tags: python, pytest

I write some plugin to DB  - which might change the results received from DB, but it is mostly not expected.
I want to know when it happens.

I have some dozens tests and i add more for any function, and i would like to have a system where all the tests being run once aganist the DB without this plugin, and   then with the plugin and having the option to compare the results. 
i need it to be ready to extend with more tests.

currently i can change in fixture if the DB will go up with or without the plugin. is there any option to make the tests run twice when each run with different fixture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your question, you can define a parametrized fixture that will select a specific impl based on current parameter (real or mock). Here is a working example using `sqlalchemy` with an SQLite database and `alchemy-mock`:

```
import pytest
from unittest import mock

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from alchemy_mock.mocking import UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock

Base = declarative_base()

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


@pytest.fixture
def real_db_session():
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///real.db')

    with engine.connect() as conn:
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=conn)
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
        session = Session()

        sample_item = Item(name='fizz')
        session.add(sample_item)
        session.commit()

        yield session


@pytest.fixture
def mocked_db_session():
    session = UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock()
    session.add(Item(name='fizz'))
    return session


@pytest.fixture(params=('real', 'mock'))
def db_session(request, real_db_session, mocked_db_session):
    backend_type = request.param
    if backend_type == 'real':
        return real_db_session
    elif backend_type == 'mock':
        return mocked_db_session
```

Test example:

```
def test_fizz(db_session):
    assert db_session.query(Item).one().name == 'fizz'
```

Execution yields:

```
$ pytest -v 
======================================= test session starts ========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-4.4.2, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.11.0
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-56558823
plugins: xdist-1.28.0, forked-1.0.2, cov-2.7.1
collected 2 items                                                                                  

test_spam.py::test_fizz[real] PASSED                                                         [ 50%]
test_spam.py::test_fizz[mock] PASSED                                                         [100%]

===================================== 2 passed in 0.18 seconds =====================================
```

#### Example: custom execution ordering

You will need to implement a custom [`pytest_collection_modifyitems`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) hook where you can resort the list of collected tests. For example, to run `real` tests first, then the rest:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    items.sort(key=lambda item: 'real' in item.name, reverse=True)
```

#### Example: collect and evaluate test results

This example is based on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51714659/2650249) to the question [How can I access the overall test result of a pytest test run during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51711988/2650249). Loosely following it:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    session.results = dict()


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    result = outcome.get_result()

    if result.when == 'call':
        item.session.results[item] = result


@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def compare_results(request):
    yield  # wait for all tests to finish

    results = request.session.results

    # partition test results into reals and mocks
    def partition(pred, coll):
        first, second = itertools.tee(coll)
        return itertools.filterfalse(pred, first), filter(pred, second)

    mocks, reals = partition(lambda item: item.name.endswith('[real]'), results.keys())
    # process test results in pairs
    by_name = operator.attrgetter('name')
    for real, mock in zip(sorted(reals, key=by_name), sorted(mocks, key=by_name)):
        if results[real].outcome != results[mock].outcome:
            pytest.fail(
                'A pair of tests has different outcomes:\n'
                f'outcome of {real.name} is {results[real].outcome}\n'
                f'outcome of {mock.name} is {results[mock].outcome}'
            )
```

Of course, this is just a stub; for example, the comparison will fail on first pair of tests with different outcomes, also the partition of results dict keys will produce uneven lists for `reals` and `mocks` if you have unparametrized tests etc.

Comment: Great response -Thanks for that!

Comment: I would like to extend your idea a bit - is so that it saves all values in dictionary in forn of <test_name, result_string>. and i want to run all tests before changing the DB type,,
and then compare the results of both tests.
is it possible?

Comment: Sure, but you won't be able to solve it with fixtures only; you'll need to implement custom hooks. I will update the answer shortly.

Comment: Hi, check whether the updated answer (examples at the bottom) suits your needs!

Comment: Yes it is - Thanks you so much!