# Create a downloadable pdf of pytest report in python

Tags: pdf, report, pytest

I need a report generated after pytest test is executed.I used allure report and pytest html report also but I am unable to get pdf as they are only providing me the html format even though their report presentation is remarkable. Is there any substitute for that so that I could get the same but in pdf format just as in Java we can get report in pdf

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on something quite similar to this question.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51714659/9691276) provides a helpful way to access test results while running pytest.

My technique is to get the results organized in a dict and then generate a markdown file I feed to pandoc through `subprocess`.

Update: this technique works fantastically.